# How to know if the computer was started automatically by the BIOS

Tags: kernel, shutdown, bios, clock

I configured my BIOS to turn on my computer automatically at a specific time each day. I would like to know of there is a way in Linux to check if the computer was turned on manually by a human or automatically by the BIOS.
Thanks.

Comment: `I configured my BIOS to turn of my computer automatically at a specific time each day.` - *off* or *on*?

Comment: On, sorry about the typo.

Comment: Linux will not know how you turned it on, but if the computer keeps that information somewhere, you **might** find it with `hwinfo`.

Comment: It's not an absolute proof but isn't the time at which the computer was turned on a strong enough evidence to distinguish between the BIOS and a human? I mean, if you set the auto-on time to 16:00, then if your computer tells you it booted at 16:00 it might be enough to conclude.

Comment: @xhienne good approach.  I'd test for time between, say, 15:59 and 16:05 to allow for a) possibly several minutes to boot up, and b) the machine being without power for long enough that the hwclock is inaccurate.

Comment: The make and model of the computer might make a difference. A server system that includes a Baseboard Management Controller (BMC) might be able to log the power-up reason to its system event log (see `ipmitool sel list`; `ipmitool chassis status`), but a basic home-grade desktop most likely won't record that information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will suit your specific use case, but `dmidecode(8)` is the first thing that pops to mind:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | egrep -i 'wake|power'
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        Power Supply State: Unknown
        Power Features: 0x000008ff
```